# Refresh Control is not hiding after refresh completed

Tags: ios, iphone, listview, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms PCL project having Android and iOS project.

When I use pull to refresh in iOS (iPhone 6 Plus), the refresh control is not hidden. The refresh control hiding is working all iPhones except some iPhone 6 Plus and 7 Plus.

Here is my code. Design:

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewCompanies"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    RowHeight="210"
    HasUnevenRows="false"
    ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <views:CompaniesListTemplate />
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Refresh command:

```
listviewCompanies.RefreshCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    BindCompanyList();
    listviewCompanies.IsRefreshing = false;
});
```

How can I hide the refresh control on all iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool _isListRefreshing;
/// <summary> 
/// List of Messages, to be bound to the view 
/// </summary> 
public bool IsListRefreshing 
{ 
get { return _isListRefreshing; } 
set { Set(() => IsListRefreshing, ref _isListRefreshing, value); } 
}
```

use IsRefreshingProperty to bind with listview

```
_listListView.SetBinding(ListView.IsRefreshingProperty, "IsListRefreshing"); 

IsListRefreshing = true;
//refresh code
IsListRefreshing = false;
```

and set IsListRefreshing flag in your refresh method. this is also good approch hidding after refresh completed

Answer (score 0):

following code is working on my machine refer this code and try to implement like this

Page Code for listview:-

```
 var _listListView = new ListView
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
        };
        _listListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "ItemSource");
        _listListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(listviewCell));
        _listListView.RefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
        {
            await _viewModel.PullToRefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            _listListView.IsRefreshing = false;
        });
```

ViewModel Code for PullToRefreshCommand:-

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Pull to refresh 
    /// </summary>
    private RelayAsyncCommand _pullToRefreshCommand;
    public RelayAsyncCommand PullToRefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _pullToRefreshCommand ??
                (_pullToRefreshCommand = new RelayAsyncCommand(async () =>
                {
                   /*do Code to download data from server to local*/
                    /*await RefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync();*/
                }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I use _listListView.IsRefreshing = true;_listListView.IsRefreshing = false; then it work for me

Comment: Make sure to call ` _listListView.IsRefreshing = false;` on the MainThread: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> _listListView.IsRefreshing = false);`. Because you're using Async/Await in the RelayAsyncCommand, there's a chance that it could be fired on a background thread.

Comment: This is the reason why legacy code exist because this kind of coding styles and practice!